# Too few arguments for call

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

So basically in other compiler(visual studio 2003-2012) this is okay but then in visual studio 2013 it is not. What could be wrong? The error is exactly at my commented line.

The "theParameters" is declared as:

```
#define theClass    CDPClient
#define theParameters   CAr & ar, DPID dpidUser, LPVOID lpBuffer, u_long uBufSize

void CDPClient::UserMessageHandler( LPDPMSG_GENERIC lpMsg, DWORD dwMsgSize, DPID idFrom )
{
    m_pDump = (BYTE*)lpMsg;
    m_nDumpSize = dwMsgSize;

    BYTE* pData = (BYTE*)lpMsg;
    for (DWORD i=0;i<dwMsgSize;i++)
    {
        pData[i] = pData[i] ^ ((BYTE)(i & 0xff) ^ 169);
        pData[i] = pData[i] ^ ((0xff - (BYTE)(i & 0xff)) ^ 86);
    }

    CAr ar((LPBYTE)lpMsg, dwMsgSize);
    GETTYPE( ar );

    void ( theClass::*pfn )( theParameters )    =   GetHandler( dw );

    if (pfn) {
        (this->*(pfn))(ar); // (ar) -> too few arguments for call. Why?
    }
    else{
        //g_DPCacheSrvr.Send( lpBuf, uBufSize, dpidUser );
    }

    m_pDump = NULL;
    m_nDumpSize = 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `theParameters`?

Comment: Hi, I have added to what 'theParameters' is.

Comment: `theParameters` is a macro that expands into 4 parameters. You're calling the function with only one argument. You're missing `dpidUser`, `lpBuffer`, and `uBufSize` arguments.

Comment: Please remove the macros, use nullptr, const and size_t.

Comment: Hi I did this "(this->*(pfn))(ar, dpidUser, lpBuffer, uBufSize);" but it's arguing that it is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a macro `theParameters`that is replaced by 4 parameters. The call hence needs 4 parameters, but you are supplying only one `ar`.

You can read more about macros [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/). The identifier is just replaced by whatever is defined. So in your code,

`void ( theClass::*pfn )( theParameters )    =   GetHandler( dw );`

becomes

`void ( theClass::*pfn )( CAr & ar, DPID dpidUser, LPVOID lpBuffer, u_long uBufSize )    =   GetHandler( dw );`

Comment: Hi there, yes that is right and I did this "(this->*(pfn))(ar, dpidUser, lpBuffer, uBufSize);" instead of  "(this->*(pfn))(ar);" but I still have errors :O

Comment: The same error, or something else? The arguments you have written are not defined, you first need to define them. I think that could be an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. My head is aching so much that I do not know what to do and etc. Thank you!